# How to convert a Java Hashmap to a javascript array properly

Tags: javascript, java, hashmap

I want to convert a Java HashMap to a javascript array where the key is inside the javascript object.

I have tried to convert the JSON to a javascript object with an array inside. 
The Java Map looks like this < string: "sequence", Object: Round>

A quick overview of the objects I want to convert from a Java object (JSON) to javascript array.

```
export class Order extends Base {
    public createdAt: Date;
    public status: OrderStatus;
    public rounds: Round[];
}
```

```
export class Round extends Base {
  public lockable: boolean;
  public locked: boolean;
  public sequence: number;
  public createdAt: string;
  public orderedItems?: Item[];
}
```

The JSON I receive from the server:

```
[
  {
    "id": "87921b20-232d-4e13-8154-5ecdcdfeea83",
    "createdAt": 1556284343924,
    "status": "UNPAID",
    "rounds": {
      "1": {
        "id": "ffd791b7-3575-4653-9e65-0d95ed027d37",
        "createdAt": 1556284343930,
        "lockable": false,
        "locked": false,
        "orderedItems": []
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "310bbdff-2c41-4e22-96da-46282e158b49",
        "createdAt": 1556284343936,
        "lockable": true,
        "locked": false,
        "orderedItems": []
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Right now the thing I want to do is the following. I thought in javascript the order of a array is not guaranteed so I wanted to add the id inside the object after fetching it from the API.

```
"2": <-- MOVE SEQUENCE inside the object like:
{
    ...
    "sequence": "2"
}
```

I couldnt find a other solution like this in javascript, but hopefully you can give me a more proper solution:

```
order.forEach(o => {
       const rounds = [];
       Object.keys(o.rounds).forEach(key => {
            o.rounds[key].sequence = key;
            rounds.push(o.rounds[key]);
       });
       o.rounds = rounds;
});
```

Comment: "The JSON I received from the server": what server? Do you have control over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're receiving doesn't contain an array of `Round`s; it contains a map, as you've observed. It would be much cleaner to look at whatever's serialising to this JSON, and correcting it so that the JSON looks like

```
[
  {
    ...
    "rounds": [
      {
        "id": "ffd791b7-3575-4653-9e65-0d95ed027d37",
        "createdAt": 1556284343930,
        "lockable": false,
        "locked": false,
        "orderedItems": []
      },
      {
        "id": "310bbdff-2c41-4e22-96da-46282e158b49",
        "createdAt": 1556284343936,
        "lockable": true,
        "locked": false,
        "orderedItems": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However if you really need to, you could do:

```
var out = []
for(var key in obj) {
    out[key] = obj[key]
}
```

You said: "I thought in javascript the order of a array is not guaranteed". Arrays are definitely ordered in Javascript. You may be thinking of something that's not an array? Therefore I see little value in adding a `sequence` property to each member of the array.

If you really want to, though, it's simple enough:

```
var out = [];
for(var key in obj) {
    out[key] = m[key]
    out[key].sequence = key        
}
```

This does all rely on the keys all being numbers, or coercable to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it by making use of [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to iterate through the values of `order.rounds`, followed by mapping the array to include the `sequence` property within each object of the array.

```js
const order = [{
  "id": "87921b20-232d-4e13-8154-5ecdcdfeea83",
  "createdAt": 1556284343924,
  "status": "UNPAID",
  "rounds": {
    "1": {
      "id": "ffd791b7-3575-4653-9e65-0d95ed027d37",
      "createdAt": 1556284343930,
      "lockable": false,
      "locked": false,
      "orderedItems": []
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "310bbdff-2c41-4e22-96da-46282e158b49",
      "createdAt": 1556284343936,
      "lockable": true,
      "locked": false,
      "orderedItems": []
    }
  }
}];

order.forEach(o => {
  const res = Object.values(o.rounds).map((object, index) => {
    object['sequence'] = index + 1;
    return object;
  });
  console.log(res)
});
```